# .csv binding to d3.js trouble

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, scatter-plot

New guy starting out in d3.js, coming from PHP/python, but my JS knowledge is very weak. I am trying to bind an X/Y position to a scatterplot and I keep getting an error

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="MNaN,NaN"

or

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute cx="NaN"
>   Error: Invalid value for  attribute cy="NaN"

and I am a little unclear about what I am doing wrong. Here is how I am going about it: Simple html page, nothing else on it except the necessary html and script (see below):

```
    <script>

    var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
        .orient("left").ticks(5);


    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.posX); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.posY); });


    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    d3.csv("test.php", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.posX = +d.posX
        d.posY = +d.posY;
    });

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.posX; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.posY; }));



svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));


svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.posX); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.posY); });


svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);


svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

});

</script>
```

The 'test.php' calls a mysql query that produces a csv formatted array. Here is the first five lines out the output (what one sees when they would navigate to localhost/test.php):

```
    "posX","posY"
    -10,50
    20,143
    14,128
    -40,8
```

etc. A few things I've made sure to note. I am calling d3.js; I get an axis drawn, just no data. The errors also reference the called d3 script, so I am sure that is working. I am happy to switch over to json if that would be a better method of approach. It is probably really obvious, but I can't make sense of it.

Thanks for the help.

Edit: my '.csv' is produced with a simple loop from a mysql array

```
     echo $posX . "," . $posY . "<br>";
```

could this (especially the br) be the issue?

Comment: Works for me with the sample data you've posted: http://plnkr.co/edit/YkjzDp8cv9FslXIdQRdp?p=preview -- note that there's no `<br>` in there.

Comment: Hm, must have something to do with the br in there. Also, it was a shocker to find it is not a scatter plot when it finally works. Haha

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I am dumb. It was the silly br 
I was calling in my php script which broke the d3.js because it thought br was another value.

Simple fix. Thanks Lars Kotthhoff.